# heap corruption when leaving scope with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, scope, c++11, unique-ptr

I face a problem similar to [void pointer returned from function heap corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706960/void-pointer-returned-from-function-heap-corruption)

The similarity is that I get "Heap corruption" message when leaving the scope where unique_ptr is used.

Here the code:

```
void CMyClass::SomeMethod ()
{
  std::unique_ptr<IMyInterface> spMyInterface;
  spMyInterface.reset(new CMyInterfaceObject()); // CMyInterfaceObject is derived from IMyInterface

  any_list.push_back(spMyInterface.get()); // any_list: std::list<IMyInterface*>

  any_list.clear(); // only clears the pointers, but doesn't delete it

  // when leaving the scope, unique_ptr deletes the allocated objects... -> heap corruption
}
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is the destructor of IMyInterface declared virtual?

Comment: you may want to add the OS and the compiler that you are using.

Comment: are you certain that `any_list.clear()` doesn't delete the object? It sounds like the heap corruption is being reported due to a double delete, when the unique_ptr's destructor is called. Try setting a breakpoint ni the destructor for `CMyInterfaceObject`

Comment: Sry. Yes, destructor is virtual.
Using WinXP, VS2010, SP1.
any_list is a std::list object -> I'll double check double deletion

Comment: -> turns out this is not of a problem (no double deletion), as this is only a list of pointers which doesn't automatically destroy objects the pointers point to (as expected).

Comment: Heap corruption can also occur if you write past the end (or beginning) of an array, and will usually not show an error _until you new or delete something_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that retains sole ownership of an object through a pointer and destroys that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope.

In your case, you have declared `std::unique_ptr<IMyInterface> spMyInterface;` inside of SomeMethod() so as soon as the execution leaves the scope of SomeMethod() your object gets destroyed.

Take a look at [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: OK, but how does this explain heap corruption?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than dll in your project, Check CRT of each dll, if each dll is built with a different CRT (C runtime library) then you get issues like this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).